# dojo grid sorting and RESTEasy JAX-RS

Tags: java, dojo, jax-rs, resteasy, dojox.grid.datagrid

Dojo grids implement sorting by by issuing requests to REST webservices like so:

```
GET http://server/request?sort(+id)
```

Where `sort(+id)` is the direction (+/-) and the column to sort on.

Currently I'm doing this, and it works, but its ugly:

```
@GET
@Path("request/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Collection<RequestDataWithCurrentStatus> getAllRequests() {
    Collection<RequestDataWithCurrentStatus> col = new ArrayList<RequestDataWithCurrentStatus>();

....

//handle the various types of sorting that can be requested by the dojo widget
String queryString = this.request.getQueryString();

//parse the dojo sort string 'sort(+id)' and sort
...

return col;
```

}

This method uses a RESTEasy injected `@Context private HttpServletRequest request` to get access to the raw query string.

I feel like I should be able to map this query string to one of RESTEasy's `@*Param` annotations in my `getAllRequests()` invocation.  But according to the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html_single/index.html#_QueryParam) for RESTEasy, there doesn't seem to be a good mapping to the screwy dojo query string from the doc.  I want to do something like this:

```
@GET
@Path("request/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Collection<RequestDataWithCurrentStatus> getAllRequests( @DojoQueryParam String sort) {
    ...
}
```

How do I marshal dojo grid query strings to RESTEasy webservice methods the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have scarce experience with the old stores / dojox grids, but in case you are using  dojo/store/JsonRest: You can change the way it sends the sort param with `sortParam`. Shamelessly snagged from the reference guide:

```
var store = new JsonRest({
  target: "/FooObject/",
  sortParam: "sortBy"
});
```

This should make requests on the form `/foo/bar?sortBy=+id`.

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/store/JsonRest.html#sorting

Comment: Awesome!  I was so focused on bending RESTEasy to my will that I didn't even think of just making the client side do the right thing.  I completely overlooked that 'sortParam' property.  Thanks!